# Is it possible to train a CoreML model on device as the app runs?

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, coreml, apple-vision

Is it possible to ship an iOS app with a `CoreML` model and then have the app continue improving (training) the model on device based on user behaviour for example? So, then the model would keep growing and improving right on the device with no need of a server support...

Comment: This would be interesting but I don't believe it's possible...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that can be done right now.  You could feed the data via a REST API back to your server to provide more training data for future releases.

Comment: No. Training involves an app update, which means approval by Apple. You have a few (sub-optimal) options. (1) Work through the approval process, which anymore may be under a day. (2) Tie your app to a server-supplied model. (3) Something nobody else has done and that Apple will approve. The CoreML workflow is *based* on training your model *before* importing it into CoreML. You could try to wait two months and see what improvements they have at WWDC '19, but I wouldn't hold your breath on this.

Comment: Like others have pointed out, it is currently very hard or not possible to do what you are trying to do. Training is a very expensive operation and it takes a lot of time to train the models. That is why this operation is performed on the server and not on the device itself. Have said that you should be able to send info to server and train the model and then download the model in the end.

Comment: What the previous commenters wrote is true. However... as of iOS 11.3 the MPS framework that Core ML is built on top of (at least for GPU computation) _can_ do training on the device. It seems plausible that Core ML will get similar functionality in iOS 12. Also, it's a bit hacky but you could write the training code yourself (possibly using MPS) and then overwrite the old learned parameters with the new ones in your mlmodel file and compile this into a new Core ML model on the device.

Comment: The main issue is that in order to train you need ( lot of ) new qualified data. So if each of you users train its own model, this is not really a model anymore

Comment: very interesting feedback so far. Thanks. It just feels like it would be a powerful thing to be able to do, meaning, start with a base model, and then tailor that model based on in-app user behavior to enhance the user experience as the app is used. A periodic sync of the model to a server would then allow for continuity from user perspective... I'll keep digging.

Comment: Check this Apple demo: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects.

In this demo you can scan object and then try to recognize. I'm not sure they train model, I think they use OBJ file to recognize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now possible with Core ML 3. 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/704/
Skip to 9:00 to see it in action. If you just want the code, skip to 13:50.

Comment: yah, saw that. Thanks for posting this though. Good stuff.

Comment: When I create a model using the "Create ML" tool on Mac, the model is not having "Updates" and XCode is not generating the training input class. Any src code on how to create an empty model and train it on the device using the app?

Answer (score 2):

***The answer is YES.***

**Since `CoreML 3` is greatly optimised – the answer is YES, you can train a CoreML model on device when your app is running**.

However, using `CoreML 2` it's not possible to train a model on device, because running `CoreML 2` app, considerably much power is required to train a model in comparison with `CoreML 3`. That's why desktop and cloud computers with power GPUs are used for creating a pre-trained models. In `CoreML 2` your MLmodel must be pre-configured and you have to include all pre-processing techniques like `Edge Detection` or `Frame Differencing` at that stage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. Apparently, when you convert your model to Core ML format with coremltools, you can pass the "respect_trainable" argument to the converter and it will automatically make the model updatable.